# Oracle: Get data for only the past half year

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query in which I have to get the data for only the last half year: All data from the current date and a half year ago.
Found this for 1 year in SQL but it's not working in Oracle:

```
SELECT ... From ... WHERE date > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the equivalent function for `dateadd` is `add_months`

```
SELECT ... From ... WHERE date > add_months(sysdate, -6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **ADD_MONTHS** in your filter predicate.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6) FROM DUAL

ADD_MONTH
---------
29-OCT-14

SQL>
```

Modify your query as:

```
WHERE date > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)
```